# Converting a list of integers into a CLPFD domain

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying to convert a list of integers to a CLPFD domain. e.g. `[1,5,7]` -> `1\/5\/7`. I tried reading the documentation, but I couldn't find anything. The only thing I found is fd_dom/2.
[fd_dom documentation.](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=fd_dom/2) Here, they are converting a domain into a list of integers (opposite of what I want). I am new to CLPFD and prolog in general. So, if someone could also explain the fd_dom documentation apart from answering my question, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use for converting a list of integers to be used as a domain (disjunction):

```
list_domain_disjunction([D|Ds],Disj) :-
        foldl(disj,Ds,D,Disj).
disj(A,B,C) :- C = \/(B,A).
```

Example:

```
?- list_domain_disjunction([1,5,7],X).
X = 1\/5\/7.
```

One can see how this disjunction is "really" represented using `write_canonical/1`:

```
?- write_canonical(1\/5\/7).
\/(\/(1,5),7)
```

Note: `list_domain_disjunction/2` is not reversible, i.e. it cannot be used to convert an disjuction to a list of integers.